# IEnumerable<> instantiated as List<> but cannot add elements

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a parent class:

```
public abstract class ObjectCollection
{
   protected IEnumerable<MyObject> Objects;

   public ObjectCollection()
   {
      LoadObjects();
   }
}
```

And a child class that inherits from it:

```
public class PublicationCollection : ObjectCollection
{
   public PublicationCollection() : base() { }

   protected override void LoadObjects() 
   {
      this.Objects = new List<PublicationObject>();
      this.Objects.Add(new PublicationObject("Example"));
   }
}
```

`PublicationObject` inherits from `MyObject`.

The line `this.Objects.Add(new PublicationObject("Example"));` throws an error because the compiler is treating it as an `IEnumerable`, though I have instantiated it as a `List<>`. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: *Why* did you type `Objects` as `IEnumerable<MyObject>`, given that you require an instance of a type that allows for adding items?

Comment: Make it a list or cast it to a list.

Comment: Because when I use a List<MyObject> in the parent class I get a casting error.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Where do you get a casting error?

Comment: why not declare Objects as an `IList<MyObject>`>

Comment: @Ric If it shouldn't be mutated after being initialized (which seems to be the case), then leaving it an `IEnumerable` is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects is declared as a IEnumerable. 
Although you initialize it with a List<> to the compiler it still is an IEnumerable.

You can fix it in your code for the provided example:

```
protected override void LoadObjects() 
   {
      var list = new List<PublicationObject>();
      list.Add(new PublicationObject("Example"));
      this.Objects = list;
   }
```

The clients outside of the class will not know that the property is a concrete list and will not be able to use the methods of List<> unless casted to List<>

```
ObjectCollection oc = ...
((List<<PublicationObject>) oc.Objects).Add(...);
```

Since you named the class as A collection, I doubt that you want to allow clients appending items to the list directly. I dedicated method Add() is the way to go here. Perhaps not obvious for now, but will safe you in the future :-)

Naming suggests that is a collection so it would be even better to make your ObjectCollection implement `ICollection`. Due to naming future users of your class expect Collection conventions.

Answer (score 1):

because `this.Objects` ie *exposed* as an `IEnumerable<T>`, so it *could* be something other than a list.

If you *know* it's a List you could just cast it:

```
((List<PublicationObject>)this.Objects).Add(new PublicationObject("Example"));
```

but you run the risk if it *not* being a list and throwing an exception at runtime.

Since this is all in the same method just create a `List` variable and use it:

```
protected override void LoadObjects() 
{
   var list = new List<PublicationObject>();
   list.Add(new PublicationObject("Example"));
   this.Objects = list
}
```

Or better, if you *need* it to be exposed as a list (or some collection you can add to), declare it as some other type, like `ICollection<MyObject>`:

```
protected ICollection<MyObject> Objects;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be needing the capability of adding items to `Objects` in the `PublicationCollection.LoadObjects()` method. Therefore, first store a reference to your list in an appropriately typed variable, later on assign that variable to the `Objects` field:

```
protected override void LoadObjects() 
{
    var objectsList = new List<PublicationObject>();
    objectsList.Add(new PublicationObject("Example"));
    this.Objects = objectsList;
}
```

The class interface remains the same like this (i.e. `Objects` will still be an `IEnumerable<PublicationObject>`), and other subclasses of `ObjectCollection` can still assign instances of types to `Objects` that do not implement any more specific interface, if that is what you are trying to achieve.